# iOS-GCM integration: does registration need to happen every time

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Do you need to register your APNS device token with GCM every time via:

```
tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:scope:options:handler
```

every time the app is launched, EVEN IF the device token is identical.

According to a sample app for GCM, every time the app is launched, `[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID` [1] is called. This is because the registration is invoked from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken which does need to be called every time the app is launched - "Device tokens can change, so your app needs to reregister every time it is launched and pass the received token back to your server." [2]

Can I store the registrationToken and deviceToken and only reregister when the deviceToken changes? The presence of GGLInstanceIDDelegate#onTokenRefresh seems to suggest that there is a mechanism to be notified when the registrationToken changes for your deviceToken, but I would like this to be confirmed.

[1]https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m#L151

[2]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Answer (score 0):

In Google's official  [GCM Client Demo App](https://github.com/google/gcm), registering every time the app starts ensures that your servers gets the Registration ID even if it lost it somehow, but that shouldn't be an issue if your Registration IDs are persisted properly in the server.

Note that google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your app that be called multiple times. Your app needs to be able to respond accordingly.

To summarize, you should always treat the Token as if it may change any time you restart your application.